# How can I stop <a> tag jumping to the target which is specified by href attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that `<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>` will just do the job,

but what I intend to do is to **specify a href, but will not jump to it when being clicked**, just like:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com" onclick="...">Link</a>
```

When I click on this link, I'd just like the `onclick` is invoked, whereas href is just a 'show' without jumping to `http://mydomain.com`.

How could this be done by javascript or css? Thanks a lot!

Comment: event.preventDefault or return false in the event handler

Comment: `onclick="someFunction(e)"` ... where `function someFunction(e) { e.preventDefault(); }`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can do this. If you must fulfill the answer within the HTML then:

```
<a href="mydomain.com" onclick="function(e){e.preventDefault()}">click here</a>
```

But better practice is to follow Andrew Spartar's solution and separate the JavaScript using a class or other selector.

Answer (score 1):

add class to the link, for example: class="not-jump"

then in jQuery add listener:

```
$( ".not-jump" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com" onclick="myFunc(event)">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
function myFunc(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   ...
}
```

and to separate html from js:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com" class="somelink">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".somelink").on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: where does the `event` argument come from? I've already have a string argument for `myFunc`, should I put `event` argument at the second place?

Comment: the event object can be passed as an argument, it has a bunch of properties and information about the event (click in your case), you can use it's preventDefault() method to prevent the default behavior for that specific event.. you can have it as second argument if you like..

Comment: btw, It is definitely recommended to separate your javascript from your html, so I'll update the answer above..